# Loop a user input textboxes in VB.NET

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio, loops

I am trying to loop these textboxes to accept multiple orders in one form in vb.net. I have trouble looping these user input textboxes. I want that the customer can be able to order another with just one customer info and translate it into the textbox TxtOrderDetails .. Any idea how to go about this code? what loop should I use. I have tried listbox but it doesnt automatically compute the amountpayable which is what i want also. I want that every order it automatically adds the amountpayable of another order...

```
 Private Sub BtnAddOrder_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnAddOrder.Click

        'used to restrict empty inputs
        If TxtCustomername.Text = "" Or TxtPhone.Text = "" Or TxtPhone.Text = "Invalid! Phone Number" Or TxtDiscount.Text = "" Or TxtDeliveryFee.Text = "" Or CboDrink.Text = "" Or CboQuantity.Text = "" Or TxtSizeprice.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Required Fields!", "Authentication Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Else
            Try

                'if there are no unwanted inputs then the program proceeds to try other wise if there is an error
                'the catch will handle it

                Dim AddOns As String
                Dim BlackPearl As String
                Dim Oreo As String
                Dim Nata As String
                Dim CoffeeJelly As String
                Dim CreamCheese As String

                AddOns = " "
                BlackPearl = " "
                Oreo = " "
                Nata = " "
                CoffeeJelly = " "
                CreamCheese = " "

                'declaring the equivalent value of the add ons check boxes
                If ChkBoxBlackPearl.Checked = True Then
                    AddOns = "Black Pearl"
                End If
                If ChkBoxOreo.Checked = True Then
                    AddOns = AddOns & "," & " Oreo"
                End If
                If ChkBoxNata.Checked = True Then
                    AddOns = AddOns & "," & " Nata De Coco"
                End If
                If ChkBoxCoffeeJelly.Checked = True Then
                    AddOns = AddOns & "," & " Coffee Jelly"
                End If
                If ChkboxCreamCheese.Checked = True Then
                    AddOns = AddOns & "," & " CreamCheese"
                End If

                'declaring the values of the payment radio buttons
                Dim Payment As String
                Payment = " "
                If RbtnGcash.Checked = True Then
                    Payment = "Gcash"
                End If
                If RbtnDebit.Checked = True Then
                    Payment = "Debit Card"
                End If
                If RbtnCoins.Checked = True Then
                    Payment = "Coins.ph"
                End If

                'declaring the values of the discount radio buttons
                If RbtnCash.Checked = True Then
                    Payment = "Cash"
                End If

                Dim DiscountRate As Double

                If RbtnPWD.Checked = True Then
                    DiscountRate = 0.05

                End If
                If RbtnSenior.Checked = True Then
                    DiscountRate = 0.1
                End If
                If RbtnStudent.Checked = True Then
                    DiscountRate = 0.03
                End If
                If RbtnDiscountNone.Checked = True Then
                    DiscountRate = 0
                End If
                'declaring the values of the transaction radio buttons
                Dim Transaction As String
                Transaction = " "
                If RbtnDelivery.Checked = True Then
                    Transaction = "15"
                End If

                If RbtnWalkin.Checked = True Then
                    Transaction = "None"
                End If

                'passing the values and converting them to numeric using val to show the total price of the add ons
                TxtTotalAddOn.Text = Val(TxtBlackPearl.Text) + Val(TxtOreo.Text) + Val(TxtNataDeCoco.Text) + Val(TxtCoffeeJelly.Text) + Val(TxtCreamCheese.Text)

                'declaring values to be computed for the total, cash and change of the customer
                Dim TotalPreDelivery As Double
                Dim FinalTotal As Double
                Dim DiscountPrice As Double
                Dim AmountPayable As Double




                TotalPreDelivery = Val(TxtTotalAddOn.Text) + Val(TxtSizeprice.Text)
                DiscountPrice = TotalPreDelivery * DiscountRate
                FinalTotal = TotalPreDelivery - DiscountPrice
                AmountPayable = (FinalTotal * Val(CboQuantity.Text)) + Val(TxtDeliveryFee.Text)

                'condition to show result it via messagebox
                If AddOns.Length <> 0 Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Choosen DRINK: " + CboDrink.Text + vbCr + "Quantity: " + CboQuantity.Text + vbCr + "Size: " + Sizename + vbCr + "Price " + TxtSizeprice.Text + vbCr + "AddOns: " + AddOns + vbCr + "Total AddOns " + TxtTotalAddOn.Text + vbCr + "Delivery Fee" + TxtDeliveryFee.Text + vbCr + "Discount " + TxtDiscount.Text)
                End If

                'process to show the results via textbox 

TxtOrderDetails.Text = ("Customer Name: " + TxtCustomername.Text + vbCrLf + "Phone Number: " + TxtPhone.Text + vbCrLf + "Address: " + TxtAddress.Text + vbCrLf + "***********************************************************" + vbCrLf + "Choosen DRINK: " + CboDrink.Text + vbCrLf + "Quantity: " + CboQuantity.Text + vbCrLf + "Size: " + Sizename + vbCrLf + "Price: Php  " + TxtSizeprice.Text + vbCrLf + "AddOns: " + vbCrLf + AddOns + vbCrLf + "Total Price of AddOns:  Php " + TxtTotalAddOn.Text + vbCrLf + "Delivery Fee:  Php  " + TxtDeliveryFee.Text + vbCrLf + "Mode Of Payment:  " + Payment + vbCrLf + "Total Price For Each MilkTea: Php  " + FinalTotal.ToString + vbCrLf + "Discount Rate:  " + TxtDiscount.Text + vbCrLf + "***********************************************************" + vbCrLf + "              Thank You For Your Order" + vbCrLf + "***********************************************************" + vbCrLf + "Date Of Transaction: " + DateTimePicker1.Text)
                

TxtAmountPayable.Text = ("Php " + AmountPayable.ToString)
```

Comment: in vb.net I want to loop these results... TxtOrderDetails.Text = 
TxtAmountPayable.Text = ("Php " + AmountPayable.ToString)

Comment: so basically my question is just how do i loop user input textboxes to another textboxes to atleast accept 10 orders and automatically adds up to each amountpayable?

Comment: pls help me how do i loop these TxtOrderDetails.Text = and

TxtAmountPayable.Text

Comment: Think your terminology might be a bit out of whack on this.  Loops have nothing to do with the process.  Since you've got a windows form there all you need to do is reset the values of your controls back to a default/starter value as the last step in the button click event, then perhaps set the focus back to the top.

Comment: do you have a sample of this

Answer (score 0):

Use `textbox.clear()` to clear the textbox you want to enter repeatedly, such as product information.
Set a global variable to record ***AmountPayable***, and then add a new price to ***AmountPayable*** with each button event.